# how to call method on timeupdate of video in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to call method ontimeupdate event in Angular 2. I have done the following but it is not getting called.

```
<video  *ngIf="switch1" [src]="content.iframeUrl(0)" (onTimeUpdate)="internal(1)"  id="frame" height="100%" width="100%" controls autoplay></video>
```

Any other ways to call it?

Comment: Yeah I have, and it is working now thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax should be as

```
(timeupdate)="internal(1)"
```